# Call Matlab function from Python script using pymatlab

Tags: python, matlab, pymatlab

Can anyone give me an idea about how to call `Matlab` function from `python` script using `pymatlab`?

`Matlab`, `pymatlab` and `python` are already properly installed.
I tried to run some `Matlab` commands from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pymatlab/) on `python` script and everything works fine. But I have no idea regarding calling `Matlab` function from `python`.

For example, I have a `Matlab` function which will receive a `string` as `argument` and will display it and return it, like below.

```
function [ name ] = print_Name(first_Name)
name=first_Name;
end
```

Thanks in advance for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first initialize a MATLAB session

```
import pymatlab
session = pymatlab.session_factory()
```

Then you can use the `run` method to call any MATLAB function that you wish

```
session.run("print_Name('name')")
```

Or you could assign a value in the workspace and use that

```
name = 'My Name'
session.putValue('name', name)
session.run('print_Name(name)')
```

If you want to get a value back, you can always assign the output of `print_Name` to a variable and call `session.getValue` to get that back into Python

```
session.run('output = print_Name(name)')
result = session.getValue('output')
```

That being said, I would highly recommend using The Mathwork's own [library](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html) for interacting with MATLAB from Python.

Comment: Thanks @Suever for your reply. `session.run('print_Name(name)')` may call this function. But how to take the returned string in a variable in `python` script?

Comment: Thanks Suever. That's what exactly I needed.